# Transforming a horizontal nav bar through media queries using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've decided to make my site mobile first so I created a header that's a block level element. It's meant to display in a column which it does very well. However, no matter what I do I can't get the display to turn into a horizontal navigation bar, when the  even using flexbox. It's meant to turn navigational at the 960 media query at the bottom of the css file.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300i" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
 <nav>
   <li><a href = "#"> Home</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#"> Heading1</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#"> Heading2</a></li>
   <li><a href = "#"> Heading3</a></li>
 </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="side1">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="main-content">
      <h2>Main-content</h2>
        <p>
          "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="side2">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
          <p>
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS

```
header {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: black;
  height: 40%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav {
  display: block;
}

nav li {
  font-weight: 700;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;

  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

li {
  border-top: grey solid 1px;

}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 45px;
}

li:nth-child(1){
  border-top: none;
   padding-bottom:10px;
  margin:0px;
}

li:nth-child(2){
padding-top:10px;
margin:0px;

}

li:nth-child(3){
margin:0px;
padding-top:10px;

}

li:nth-child(4){
margin:0px;
padding-top:10px;

}


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.side1 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  width:100%;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-content {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);

 width:100%;
 background: white;
 border-color: black;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.side2 {
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: -1px 2px 17px 0px    rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 width:100%;
 background: white;
 border-color: black;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width : 726px) {


@media screen and (min-width : 900px) {
  .header {
  display:flex;
    }

    .nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

  .container  {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .main-content {
    border-left: lightgrey 1px solid;
    border-right: lightgrey 1px solid;

    width: 33.3%;
  }

  .side1 {

      width: 30%;
  }


  .side2 {

    width: 30%;
  }

}
```

Comment: Your elements are `<header>` and `<nav>`. Your CSS selectors in the media query are `.header` and `.nav`. They are not matching. You're targeting classes that don't exist. Target the elements instead. Remove the periods in the selectors.

Comment: Note also that `li` elements *must* be the children of `ol` or `ul` or `menu` containers ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)). You have them as children of `nav`. This is invalid HTML. Since you already use `nav` (and as a flex container), I would suggest you remove the `li` elements, making the `a` elements the children.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `.header` to `header` and  `.nav` to `nav` to defined class for header and nav tag in your media query. The dot `.` should not be use since you are not targeting a class but rather a tag.

```
    @media screen and (min-width : 900px) {
  header {
  display:flex;
    }

    nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

  .container  {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .main-content {
    border-left: lightgrey 1px solid;
    border-right: lightgrey 1px solid;

    width: 33.3%;
  }

  .side1 {

      width: 30%;
  }


  .side2 {

    width: 30%;
  }

}
```